# Override Google Calendar default settings for reminders

Tags: android, android-calendar, reminders

In my app, the users can add special events to their Google Calendar. I want that the events will be added without any alarm/reminder/notification. Some of the users' calendars have default settings for the reminders, as "A day before the event, at 9:00".

How can I add the events so they will not have any alarm at all despite the default settings?

```
    ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
    eventValues.put("calendar_id", calendarId);
    eventValues.put("title",title);
    eventValues.put("allDay", 1);
    eventValues.put("dtstart", dtstart);
    eventValues.put("dtend", dtend );
    eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1);  // I tried both 0 and 1, none of them solved the problem!
    eventValues.put("hasAttendeeData", 1);
    eventValues.put("availability",1);
```

Edit: It seems that the reminders were added only after the events were synchronized with Google's services, some minutes after, not immediately. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Have you tried deleting all event reminders after adding an event?

Comment: No. I'll try and update here.

Comment: How can I delete reminders?

Comment: `context.getContentResolver().delete(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID + "=?", new String[]{Long.toString(eventId)});`

Comment: I tried to delete the reminders (with your code) right after adding the events but it seems that the reminders were added only a few minutes after - when the events were synchronized with Google's servers. So there was nothing to delete yet.

Comment: Instead of deleting reminders after creating event, you can set a `BroadCastReceiver` on `CalendarProvider`. It will fired when a change happens in provider contains adding reminder. So if you have saved your event ids for example in a `SharedPreference` you can delete reminders in `onReceive()` method.

Comment: `<receiver android:name="CalendarChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: I'll try it. You can write both your answers as an answer so if it'll solve my problem I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `BroadCastReceiver` on `CalendarProvider`. It will fired when any changes happen in provider:

```
<receiver android:name="CalendarChangeReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" /> 
    <data android:scheme="content" /> 
    <data android:host="com.android.calendar" /> 
</intent-filter> </receiver>
```

So when reminders are added to events, this will fired. You can save your inserted events ids in `SharedPreferences` and then delete reminders in `onReceive()`:

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID + "=?", new String[]{Long.toString(eventId)});
```